# Ruby Selenium Screenshot to specific File location

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation

I'm having some trouble with taking a screenshot and saving it to a specific file location:

I having **working** code which saves a screenshot to the original file location of my workspace:

***driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")***

I want to be able to save this screenshot in its own folder in my C://Username//RubyTutorial//Screenshots//Screenshot.png

C://Username//RubyTutorials is an already existing directory, I would like the code to create a 'Screenshots' folder and then save the image in that folder.

How am I able to do this?

I have tried:
***driver.save_screenshot("C://Username//RubyTutorial//Screenshots//Screenshot.png")***

but I get errors of "No such file or directory"

I have tried different attempts of switching the "//" to "/", "\" and "\"

but still no luck.

Thank you :)

Comment: If you don't want to manually create the Screenshots directory, you could use `Dir::mkdir` to create it and then execute `.save_screenshot`.

Comment: Did you try to a double backslash? That is a \ escaped with a \ resulting in ´\\´

Comment: @orde do you have any example code for the Mkdir method? I can get the screenshots outputing to an already created folder, but cant make a folder create itself, then save the screenshot to that folder destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple, contrived example that demonstrates how to create a directory before saving the screenshot using [`Dir::mkdir`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-mkdir):

```
Dir.mkdir "C:\\screenshots"
driver.save_screenshot "C:\\screenshots\\Screenshot.png"
```

As @Cagy79 points out, you have to escape the backslash with a double backslash.

Also, keep in mind that an error will be thrown if the directory exists, so you may want to check for it (e.g. `Dir.mkdir("C:\\screenshots") unless Dir.exist?("C:\\screenshots")`).  And take a look at the documentation.  There's a lot in the `Dir` class that can make your life easier.